# Too much CPU Usage for an app in ruby on rails, mongodb and jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, jquery

This is more of an architecture question than a technical one.I have an app which has the following structure.(Hypothetically changed for security reason)

1. A collection that stores a document for movie with many fields like name,release date director etc.(approximately 10 fields per json with a total of 1000 documents in the collection)
2. I take the docId from each document of movies collection and make a separate collection that stores the countries,one IMAGE(stored in base64 encoded string in db) and a URL among other things.
3. Now on page load i have tried the following architectures.
4. One ajax call for loading all movies from its collection(this call involves reading data from mongo and multiple gsub operations to create an html structure to render on page).After this call completes, fire ajax calls in a for loop that brings the countries for movie specific document(again involves multiple gsubs and also displaying image).This approach has a lot of CPU USAGE so needed to be changed.
5. Approach 2:  call to bring all movies and display data and then batches of ten to bring countries.
6. Approach 3: combine call to bring movies and countries together for 5 movies. Fire this on done of previous call.

I am using ruby 1.8.7 so not much use of threading.All the three approaches have almost same cpu usage(>55%).I cannot change the way database is created. But i need to improve the performance of my page. Please give me suggestions for the same.

Comment: The query takes a lot of time? are you using indexes?

Comment: No indexes, the query is not taking that much time.The ajax requests complete in around 600ms for content of length 200kb.Is that normal or not.I have a mediocre net connection.

Comment: Are you measuring CPU with your app running on the same machine as the browser or are these on separate machines? You really need to break down your metric profile more clearly, i.e.: time/CPU for MongoDB server vs Ruby code vs browser rendering. For MongoDB tuning you should definitely look at adding appropriate indexes by [explaining common queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) and using the [Database Profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/).

Comment: An Application Performance Monitoring solution like New Relic or App Dynamics may also give you some quick insight into the performance profile of your application.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of a later question on the same subject: [High Cpu usage on running an app in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180256).